# content not updating through database with elementor plugin on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, elementor

I'm a CS student and it's currently my first internship ever. My mission is to modify the content of wordpress post through database (and later make an automation script) but the problem is that the website uses Elementor plugin. Whenever i make the modification through elementor interface, it shows up on the website and inside the databse table wp_post, but if i modify the content in the database, it doesn't show up on the website. However, if i turn off the elementor plugin, the modification does show up (but the style of the site is broken)

Does anybody know how I could update the content via the database without turning off elementor ?
Thanks so much in advance and have a great day

Comment: Check the database for some specific elementor settings table that holds values which may overwrite the one you are trying to change

Comment: @manqlele i have tried to do so by looking into the meta_post table that has meta value _elementor_ something, but no luck so far, do you know if i should be looking somewhere else ?